# Give read operations priority over write

Tags: linux, performance, io

I'm working on a system where I have a program that outputs high quality videos for a tv connected to an HDMI (raw 1080p data for instance) and I'm having an issue that when I copy some files to my hard drive it reflects on the FPS being displayed in the output. Since it only occurs when I'm copying files to the same disk (I'm using ssd, btw), the write operation is interfiering in the read operation.
So is there any way that I can tune my hard drive to give priority for reading?

Or do I have to go in some other direction?

Comment: This sound like QOS management for disk I/O or application I/O prioritization for me. Maybe [How to throttle per process I/O to a max limit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit) is a good entry point.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't state what system/OS you're using so it's going to be tough to give useful advice...